# Where was CUDA installed (it's not in default path)?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, cuda

I installed CUDA in my Ubuntu 18.04 by performing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

CUDA is indeed installed as `nvcc --version` works, and so do some scripts I have in Python which use `PyCuda`.

The problem is thast I need to know where CUDA was installed to build a library that requires this location as a parameter, but there is no such file as the default `/usr/local/cuda`.

Is there a way to know where this folder is? How can I look it up?

Comment: @Terrance The answer starts with "NOTE: I have only verified this works with 16.04 and 17.10. Just tried 18.04 and it does not work.", and I'm on 18.04.

Comment: That's why I removed the comment

Comment: `dpkg-query -L nvidia-cuda-toolkit` should show you where it is installed.

Comment: @Terrance you mean dpkg ...

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you!  Luckily I was able to fix it in time.  =)

Comment: @Terrance That returns lots of directories. How do I know which one is the one that should be input in the build command instead of the standard /usr/local/cuda ?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't think the cuda from the default repos is the full version for building, even though it claims that the `-dev` is installed.  Maybe soon NVIDIA will post the newest up in http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ as for right now they stop at 1710

Comment: @Terrance So what do you suggest? Should I install it some other way?

Comment: I don't think that it is fully compatible with 18.04 yet.  Because the older versions put in the lib64, etc folders that can be used.  There isn't a version yet for 18.04.  I guess you could go back to 16.04 LTS where it is fully supported.

Comment: Can you give an example of an app you are trying to build that requires CUDA?  I might be able to duplicate what you are experiencing and could possibly figure out what directory is needed.

Comment: @Terrance `RSomoclu` is the library, which can be found [here](https://github.com/peterwittek/somoclu). I had to run this command: `R CMD INSTALL Rsomoclu_1.6.2.1.tar.gz --configure-args=/usr/local/cuda`, but I didn't know which path to write on the configure arguments. I ended up following your suggestion though, and moved back to Ubuntu 16.04, where now everything works. If you find the answer, however, feel free to put it here so it can help future readers (and myself, if I upgrade again to 18.04).